# REST URL concept for subObjects

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I want to build my application RESTFul.

Whats the normal URI concept for subObjects.

My Example:

I have a some users. I get a user by `/users/:id`. Now this user can be rated. Is the best concept to do the userRatings (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) over `/users/:id/ratings` or handle them as an own object over `/ratings/`. Or a mix of both?

My questions:

- When it is `/ratings/` how i get a list of ratings for a specific
  user (`/ratings/?userId=1?`).
- Is the object normally in the URI plural or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **URL scheme depends** largely on what you need to do with your data model, e.g. how you want to query those ratings:

- if you only ever want to display a single user's ratings, put them under `/users/:id/ratings`
- if you want something like "10 top-rated *users*", consider something like `GET /users?toprated` -- here you're looking for users, so the URL should signify that by being `/users`
- if you want to get *ratings* across several users, e.g. to find all ratings containing the word "outstanding", `/ratings/` makes more sense: The search is then naturally expressed as `GET /ratings?q=outstanding` -- here you want ratings so the URL should be `/ratings` plus a request parameter to restrict what kind of ratings you want

In either case, unless you're building a huge, public API and expect lots of clients right on launch day, go with what works and change the URL scheme if you need to.

As for the **singular/plural debate**: Use plural for path segments, i.e. `/users`, `/ratings` because it follows naturally from REST's building blocks of a "resource" and "collections of resources": There's the collection of users at `/users` (accepting GET, POST) and there's a single user at `/users/:id` (accepting GET, PUT, DELETE).

Comment: Thanks for this answer.
Helped me a lot planning the structure of my application.